# Positioning and Sizing a video player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a webpage that shows videos.

Here is how my webpage will look:

http://tinypic.com/r/kbozh4/8

I want the video to play exactly where the screen is in the picture and be the exact size of the screen. Could some one help me by providing a good link to a tutorial on how to do this. I am not a complete novice but my knowledge of HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript is limited. so nothing too complex please.

This is the code I am using just now to show the video player, video and size it:

```
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="455" height="455" poster="../Images/JungleAnimals.png" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
                    <source src="../Videos/JungleAnimals.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following html code:

```
<img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/kbozh4.jpg">
<video src="Your_video_url" autoplay>
```

and the css code:

```
video {
 background: #000;
 position: absolute;
 left: 45px;
 top: 31px;
 width: 376px;
 height: 208px;
}
```

See an working example at http://jsfiddle.net/tLZSB/2/

Answer (score 0):

Create a containing `div` for your video element

```
<div id="cinema">
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" poster="http://lorempixel.com/376/208/" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
        <source src="../Videos/JungleAnimals.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
</div>
```

and set its background to your cinema image:

```
#cinema {
    background-image: url(http://oi61.tinypic.com/kbozh4.jpg);
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 344px;
}
```

By setting its position to `relative` you can position your video relative to the containing div:

```
#cinema video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 37px;
    top: 23px;
    width: 376px;
    height: 208px;
}
```

That way you can move the whole thing around as a unit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G22Wj/